# Not able to retrieve picture data in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi

I'm trying to retrieve the pictures from my `strapi` client in my `nextjs` project.

So far I have a api call file for this:

```
export function getPostSlideshowArray(post) {
var images = [];
var api_base_url = process.env.API_BASE_URL;
post['Featured Images'].forEach(featuredImages => {  
    if(featuredImages.formats){
    images.push({
        original: api_base_url + featuredImages.url ,
        thumbnail: api_base_url + featuredImages.formats.thumbnail.url,
    })
}
    else{
        images.push({
            original: api_base_url + featuredImages.url ,
           
        }) 
    }
});
return images;
}

export function getScreenPostsImages(posts, lang) {
    var images = [];
    var api_base_url = process.env.API_BASE_URL;
    images = [];
    posts.forEach(post => {
        images.push({
            src: api_base_url + post['Featured Images'][0].url,
            caption: post['Title (' + lang.toUpperCase() + ')']
        })
    });
    return images;
}
```

and this is my view code:

```
<div id="Gridview">
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            {postsToShow.map((image, index) => (
              <>
                <Grid item xs={6} container spacing={3}>
                  <Grid container justify="flex-start">
                    <a
                      style={{
                        textDecoration: "none",
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        color: "white",
                      }}
                      replace="true"
                      href={
                        "/" +
                        props.lang.toUpperCase() +
                        "/post/" +
                        encodeURIComponent(props.roomName) +
                        "/" +
                        encodeURIComponent(props.screenName) +
                        "/" +
                        encodeURIComponent(image.caption)
                      }
                    >
                      <figure style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                        <div
                          style={{
                            width: "418px",
                            height: "196px",
                            textAlign: "center",
                            position: "relative",
                          }}
                        >
                          <img
                            style={{
                              maxWidth: "95%",
                              textAlign: "center",
                              position: "absolute",
                              top: "50%",
                              left: "50%",
                              transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
                            }}
                            src={image.src}
                          />
                        </div>
                        <figcaption>
                          <ScreenToPostLink
                            lang={props.lang}
                            roomName={props.roomName}
                            screenName={props.screenName}
                            postName={image.caption}
                          >
                            {" "}
                          </ScreenToPostLink>{" "}
                        </figcaption>
                      </figure>
                    </a>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <div className="extraspace"></div>
              </>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </div>
```

But I'm getting this error when I try to run the code:

[image]

So how do I fix this error so that I can display my images that are in my `strapi` client can be shown here in the `gridview`. Any leads, please?

**Edit:**
getScreenPostsImages is calling getScreen in my apiGet with the following code:

```
export async function getScreen(screenName, lang, roomName) {
let api_base_url = process.env.API_BASE_URL;
const room = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await getRoom(roomName)));

var screenObject = {};
screenObject = room.screens.filter(screen => screenName &&( (screen['Name (EN)'].toLowerCase() == screenName.toLowerCase()) || (screen['Name (AR)'] == screenName)))[0];
const response = await fetch(api_base_url + "/screens/" + screenObject.id);
screenObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await response.json()));
return screenObject;
}
```

Comment: getScreenPostsImages is a method in my lib folder under the main nextjs folder and posts is a collection type in my strapi. Here is the github link for more clarification: https://github.com/Jay-Bruh/TNA-v3-master.git

Comment: Is your `getScreen` function (in `lib/apiGet.js`) returning the expected output? Is the `fetch` there successful and returning the right results?

Comment: No I get this error there: FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:4040/screens/undefined reason: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

Comment: That's because the `screenObject.id` you're passing to it is `undefined`. Make sure you pass a valid id before making the request.

Comment: I included my getScreen function above and when I run this code I get this error: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: That means `room.screens` is not defined, so make sure the `getRoom` function is also successful and returns the expected output.